# Loading type from new assembly using structuremap.net

Tags: inversion-of-control, ioc-container, structuremap

I'm playing around with structuremap.net and what I'm trying to do (I'm not sure if it possible or not) is loading type implementing specific interface and this type exist in assembly that's not refrence in my application, for example i want to drop new assembly in the application directory and configure the IOC container to load , currently i'm not using a configuration file i'm just testing the concept :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to scan all Assemblies in the application directory:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(
    c => c.Scan( s => 
    {
        s.AssembliesFromBaseDirectory();
        s.AddAllTypesOf<IMyInterface>().NameBy(type => type.Name);
    })
);
```

or specific assemblies in a specific folder:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(
    c => c.Scan( s => 
    {
        s.AssembliesFromPath("thePath", assembly => assembly.GetName()
            .Name.Contains("Extension"));
        s.AddAllTypesOf<IMyInterface>();
    })
);
```